Appending random digits until a prime is created. Does this terminate with probability 1? And what does the distribution of number of steps look like?
Similar to the discussion here: Number of digits until a prime is reached
But I'm asking not about expectation, but about the probability of termination. Using the Prime Number Theorem works as a heuristic, but the issue is that the numbers resulting from the digits drawn are not uniformly sampled.
For example, if we instead append digits on the left, then starting with 4 will never produce a prime.
Is there a way to show that the process of appending digits on the right does terminate with probability one?

Interesting question. To my understanding, this would require the possibility of getting a sequence that zeroed out any future possibility of generating a prime. In other words, is there some sequence of digits for which no prime number starts with that sequence?

@NuclearHoagie FYI, re: your last sentence of "In other words, is there some sequence of digits for which no prime number starts with that sequence?", the answer is no. For example, from the RHS Related list, see How can we turn any number into a prime number by simply adding more digits?. Note there was also another quite similar question asked here within just the last day or two, but I can't find it now, so it may have been deleted.

Unfortunately, the state of the art guarantees that for all sufficiently large $n$, there is a prime number between $n$ and $n + n^{0.525}$, which roughly speaking says "if you have a $k$-digit number, then out of all the extensions of it to a number with $\frac k{1-0.525} \approx 2.1k$ digits, at least one is prime". This leaves open the possibility that the number of digits more than doubles between successive opportunities to get a prime number, and then there's a positive probability we miss them all.
